# referencing jquery script in a view without a layout is causing different reactions after the POST

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view that I call as a modal Popup for inserting or editing data.
I have implemented choosen js for the DropDownList on my view and that is where the problem starts.
When I do not have a reference to the jquery script, everything works fine, after the POST it redirects me to the Index page and refreshes the table.

But, as soon as I put the `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>` ,
after the POST it redirects me to the JSON file in a browser. I get this
:
[image]

Can I somehow implement this? Or I must return RedirectToaction instead of JSON in my Controller?

This is my view:

```
@model aspEvidencijaZgrada.Models.Korisnik

@{
    if (Session["userID"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Login/Index");
    }

}

    <h2 style="text-align:center">Stanar</h2>
    <hr />

    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddOrEdit", "Korisnik", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "return SubmitFormK(this)" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal" style="padding-left:150px;">

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.imePrezime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.imePrezime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.imePrezime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.jmbg, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.jmbg, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.jmbg, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.brStana, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.brStana, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.brStana, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.kvadratura, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.kvadratura, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.kvadratura, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.id_zgrade, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.id_zgrade, new SelectList(Model.ZgradaCollection, "ID", "naziv"), new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddlZgrada" })

                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.id_zgrade, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>


            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="form-group" style="padding-left:150px;">
                <input type="submit" value="Sacuvaj" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-right:25px;" />
                <input type="reset" value="Ponisti" class="btn" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }


<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
          $("#ddlZgrada").chosen();
    });

</script>
```

This is my controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddOrEdit(Korisnik model)
        {

            try
            {
                using (conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
                {

                    if (model.ID != 0)
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        string query = "UPDATE Korisnik SET imePrezime=@imePrezime,jmbg=@jmbg,brStana=@brStana,kvadratura=@kvadratura,id_zgrade=@id_zgrade WHERE ID=@id";
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", model.ID);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imePrezime", (object)model.imePrezime ?? DBNull.Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jmbg", (object)model.jmbg ?? DBNull.Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brStana", (object)model.brStana ?? DBNull.Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kvadratura", (object)model.kvadratura ?? DBNull.Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_zgrade", model.id_zgrade);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        return Json(new { success = true, message = "Update uspesan" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


                    }

                    else
                    {
                        conn.Open();

                        string query = "INSERT INTO Korisnik (imePrezime,jmbg,brStana,kvadratura,id_zgrade) VALUES(@imePrezime,@jmbg,@brStana,@kvadratura,@id_zgrade)";

                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imePrezime", (object)model.imePrezime ?? DBNull.Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jmbg", (object)model.jmbg ?? DBNull.Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brStana", (object)model.brStana ?? DBNull.Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kvadratura", (object)model.kvadratura ?? DBNull.Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_zgrade", (object)model.id_zgrade ?? DBNull.Value);


                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        return Json(new { success = true, message = "Uspesno sacuvano" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new { success = false, message = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }



        }
```

And this is my JS code for calling the Popup and submiting:

```
function PopupForm(url) {
        var formDiv = $('<div/>');

        $.get(url)
            .done(function (response) {
                formDiv.html(response);
                Popup = formDiv.dialog({
                    autoOpen: true,
                    resozable: false,
                    title: "Podaci o stanaru",
                    height: 600,
                    width: 900,
                    open: function (event, ui) {
                        $('.ui-dialog').css('overflow-x', 'hidden');
                        $('.ui-dialog-content').css('overflow-x', 'hidden');


                    },


                    close: function () {
                        $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
                        Popup.dialog('destroy').remove();
                    }
                });
            });
    }

    function SubmitFormK(form) {
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
        if ($(form).valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: form.action,
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        Popup.dialog('close');
                        var table = $("#tableKorisnik").DataTable();
                        table.ajax.reload();
                        $.notify(data.message, {
                            globalPosition: "top center",
                            className: "success"
                        });



                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Your current action method code is returning Json response. It will return Json response only irrespective of you have jQuery loaded in the page or not. If you do not have jQuery loaded, your other plugins which relies on jQuery will fail